# Angular Lazy loaded module components not rendering in production mode, but working in development mode

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

I am encountering an issue with my lazy loaded module where the components within the module are not rendering in production mode. However, in development mode, the lazy loaded module works perfectly fine.

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { UserAuthComponent } from './accounts/user-auth/user-auth.component';
import { AuthGuardGuard } from './accounts/guards/auth-guard.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
  canActivate: [AuthGuardGuard], 
  canMatch: [AuthGuardGuard],
  data: {
    usertype: 'user'
  },
  loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule),
 },
  { path: '',
  canMatch: [AuthGuardGuard],
  data: {
    usertype: 'restaurant'
  }, 
  loadChildren: () => import('./restaurant/restaurant.module').then(m => m.RestaurantModule),
  },
  { path: '',
  canMatch: [AuthGuardGuard],
  data: {
    usertype: 'delivery'
  },
  loadChildren: () => import('./delivery/delivery.module').then(m => m.DeliveryModule),
  },
  {path: 'auth/:type', component: UserAuthComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'auth/login' } 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

user.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { UserRoutingModule } from './user-routing.module';
import { UserComponent } from './user.component';
import { UserHomeComponent } from './user-home/user-home.component';
import { UserCartComponent } from './user-cart/user-cart.component';
import { UserHeaderComponent } from './user-header/user-header.component';
import { AccountsModule } from '../accounts/accounts.module';
import { UserSearchComponent } from './user-search/user-search.component';
import { RestaurantListComponent } from './user-home/restaurant-list/restaurant-list.component';
import { RestaurantDetailComponent } from './user-home/restaurant-detail/restaurant-detail.component';
import { UserSidebarComponent } from './user-header/user-sidebar/user-sidebar.component';
import { UserZoneComponent } from './user-zone/user-zone.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { CartBtnComponent } from './user-home/cart-btn/cart-btn.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        UserComponent,
        UserHomeComponent,
        UserCartComponent,
        UserHeaderComponent,
        UserSearchComponent,
        RestaurantListComponent,
        RestaurantDetailComponent,
        UserSidebarComponent,
        UserZoneComponent,
        CartBtnComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        UserRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        AccountsModule,
        AccountsModule,
        FormsModule,
    ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

ng build console:

```
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files           | Names                        |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
main.8ddfb5fd8035f494.js      | main                         | 303.58 kB |                79.10 kB
polyfills.7949269726d5ea9b.js | polyfills                    |  33.06 kB |                10.64 kB
styles.f1368471cb940c76.css   | styles                       |  18.75 kB |                 3.91 kB
runtime.daf305e1e7389719.js   | runtime                      |   2.85 kB |                 1.38 kB

                              | Initial Total                | 358.24 kB |                95.03 kB

Lazy Chunk Files              | Names                        |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
43.72a8508c0f728755.js        | user-user-module             | 225.87 kB |                52.26 kB
712.9a60d83f44d3060c.js       | user-user-module             |  66.72 kB |                13.49 kB
458.b26b659a64c7d2fa.js       | restaurant-restaurant-module |  41.05 kB |                 8.92 kB
453.72cf6c159d859ab9.js       | user-user-module             |  12.61 kB |                 3.79 kB
650.8dc691d3665cc26a.js       | delivery-delivery-module     |   7.80 kB |                 2.83 kB
common.def02b7064e8b64c.js    | common                       | 274 bytes |
```

Expected Behavior:
When the lazy loaded module is loaded in production mode, I expect the components within the module to render correctly. They should display the intended content and functionality as designed.

Actual Behavior:
In production mode, the components within the lazy loaded module are not rendering at all. Instead, I am seeing empty spaces or placeholders where the components should be. No error messages or warnings are displayed in the console.